# File explorer for Windows that allows to see all files in all subfolders of a folder at a glance

Tags: windows, file-management

For example, given the file structure:

```
Folder_1
    Folder_1-1
        File_1-1_1.jpg
        File_1-1_2.jpg
    Folder_1-2
        Folder_1-2-1
            File_1-2-1_1.jpg
        File_1-2_1.jpg
```

A view would then give me something like this

```
File_1-1_1.jpg
File_1-1_2.jpg
File_1-2-1_1.jpg
File_1-2_1.jpg
```

Preferablly, the explorer should also have a prieview pane for jpg, pdf files.

Comment: What a bout a simple file-system search tool like Agent Ransack started to search in the Folder_1 and the query `*.jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/). It works on Windows, is super fast and free.

It's not exactly a file explorer, though. How would it work?
In the menu, activate "Match path", then type the path into the textbox. Done.

[image: Search Everything]

It has a preview feature, and I actually didn't know this until now. So I can't judge about that yet.

[image: Search Everything preview]

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/). Dual panel file explorer, it has a "Show all files in current directory and all subdirs" option (Ctrl + B) that will show all the files in the current directory and in all its subdirs.

[image]

Then you can sort the files, rename, preview, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but perhaps look at the Windows Subsystem For Linux. It might support the `locate`/ `updatedb` Unix command line tools. `updatedb` is the pathname indexer, and [`locate`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)) is the query tool.

You can then run simple command like

`locate File_1-1_`

to find all files containing the substring `File_1-1_`, and `locate` would give you the absolute paths, in a terminal window.

The you can do filtering such as

`locate File_1-1_   | xargs -i basename "{}"` to get only the filenames, just like in your post.

For filtering and previewing images you could do

`locate File_1-1_   | grep "jpg\|png" | xargs -i convert -resize 100x "{}" "preview.{}"`

This would create a bunch of new thumbnails with filenames such as `preview.DSC0012345.jpg`, all with 100 px width,  in the current directory.

`convert` is part of the [Imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) set cof command line tools. So you'd have to install Imagemagick (or graphicsmagick) first.

I am sure Powershell can do something like these commands too.